# Add Owl Carousel to Homepage in Magento CE 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, cms, css

I was able to locally create the carousel but now sure how to implement this into Magento.

I have my CSS, Js and Images. Images are in Magento already but not sure where to put the CSS and Js files.

Also my index.html file. Do I need to add this to the Homepage CMS Page > Content?

### Update

I tried: 
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You can add HTML to the CMS, if you turn off the WYSIWYG editor, i.e. it should look like this:

[image: editor]

Including CSS and JS files on certain CMS pages can be done via layout updates. This is XML code that gets inserted in this form:

[image: layout]

```
<reference name="head">
  <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>owl/your.js</name></action>
  <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>owl/your.cs</name></action>
</reference>
```

Add as many `<action>` elements in this form as you need.

The file path `owl/your.css` is relative to `skin/frontend/[package]/[theme]`, so upload your files there. If you don't know, what to use as [package] and [theme], look it up in System > Configuration > Design

Comment: Hi thanks for your help! Still having some issues, no sure If i'm doing this right yet.
I added the css and js file and I did what you instructed for the content and layout (see screen shots in Answer).

I only get the images showing on the front-end. Please advise, much appreciated.

Comment: Can you update your question with the code that you used?

Comment: I added files to C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\skin\frontend\rwd\default

CMS > Content:
<div id="slider" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
<div class="item"><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/media/wysiwyg/image1.jpg"}}" alt="" /></div>
</div>

cont..

Comment: CMS > Layout XML:
<reference name="head">
  <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js</name></action>
  <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/owl.carousel.min.js</name></action>
  <action method="addCss"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/owl.carousel.css</name></action>
  <action method="addCss"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/owl.theme.css</name></action>
  <action method="addCss"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/owl.transitions.css</name></action>
</reference>

There was already code in here so added this on top of it.

Comment: Looks right. But shouldn't there be something like `<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() { $("#slider").owlCarousel(); });</script>` in the HTML to activate the slider?

Comment: Yes there is, but don't know where/how it should go in. This is new to me:
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 
$("#slider").owlCarousel({
 
navigation : false, // Show next and prev buttons
        slideSpeed : 300,
        paginationSpeed : 400,
        singleItem:true
 
        // "singleItem:true" is a shortcut for:
        // items : 1, 
        // itemsDesktop : false,
        // itemsDesktopSmall : false,
        // itemsTablet: false,
        // itemsMobile : false
 
 });
    
 });
 </script>

Comment: Right into the content. But the CMS might actually not allow script tags, so better put this into an own JS file, like `owl.homepage.js` and include it the same way as the others.

Comment: No doesn't work for me.
Created new js file added to the path, added the action with the rest: <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/owl.homepage.js</name></action>
Cleared caches, flushed mage cache

Comment: Do you see any of the files within `<head>...</head>` if you look at the source code of the home page in your browser? If not: clear the Magento cache

Comment: Yes it's there when I inspect element

Comment: Then your problem seems to be related to how you instantiate the slider and I can't help you anymore.

Comment: I appreciate your time. I'll try again from the top!

Answer (score 0):

I've attached the following JS/CSS files into my local.xml, you can get Jquery from [here](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js):

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><script>js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js</script></action>

<!-- Owl Carousel -->
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><script>js/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.js</script></action>
<action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.css</stylesheet></action>
<action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.css</stylesheet></action>
<action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/owlcarousel/owl.theme.default.min.css</stylesheet></action>
```